# Vertical aligning in longtable environment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, longtable

i have got a longtable that spans over many pages and contents both graphics and text. Now i want to align both columns vertically to the top, but the text column is being automatically parsed to the bottom.. How do i change this?

This is my example code:

```
\begin{longtable}{|p{6cm}|p{9cm}|}

\hline
\textbf{Visualisation} & \textbf{Explaining} \\ \hline
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{pic/pic1.pdf}
& text\\\hline

\end{longtable}
```

i want that the "text" is being placed on the top of the second column.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

By default the baseline of the image is at the bottom  you could use

```
\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics{....}}
```

to move the baseline to the top but that may be to far, you may want around a baseline of height  something like

```
\raisebox{\normalbaselineskip-\height}{\includegraphics{....}}
```

if you have the `calc` package loaded.

The `adjustbox` package probably gives a nicer interface to this, so you might like to consult its documentation.

Comment: `\adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics{...}}`