# NewDocumentEnvironment causes extra row

Tags: environments, xparse

When I use `NewDocumentEnvironment` of xparse and place a table to be inside this environment, I get an extra row at the end. Same code does not cause extra row in standard newenvironment. Is there a solution to this problem? I have tried using `\ignorespaces` and made entire thing single line without spaces, still the same result. I have compiled a MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{test}{}{%
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}\hline%
        A & B & C \\\hline%
}{%
    \end{tabular}%
}

\newenvironment{testtwo}{%
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}\hline%
        A & B & C \\\hline%
}{%
    \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{test}
        This & does not & work\\\hline
    \end{test}

    ~\\~\\

    \begin{testtwo}
        This & does & work\\\hline
    \end{testtwo}   
\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image: result]

Comment: 1) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42156/too-long-vertical-lines-in-table 2) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277378/too-long-vertical-lines-in-table-when-declarations-must-remain-on-distinct-lines 3) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285333/build-table-in-new-command-results-in-too-long-vertical-lines

Comment: Thank I now understand the problem better, I thought about extra space causing new row. But that does not help to solve it though, unless I would change `\NewDocumentEnvironment`. Is there a way around it?

Comment: David's answer here http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277696/46716 defines a new table environment that you should be able to use.